# "Keys to car" or "keys of car"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I saw in a grammar book a sentence that looks weird to me.

> Kyle gave Loren the **keys to** his new car.

I would have hoped to see *of* instead of *to* but it must be correct since it was the sample sentence.

> Kyle gave Loren the **keys of** his new car.

What grammar rule is this?

Comment: Give them some time! Your question has already been discussed in chat just now. You will probably get nice Ngrams shortly. In summary: it is *to*, and there is no good reason—it's just idiom.

Comment: You can also say "one of the keys to the success."

Comment: @kiamlaluno: sort of: "one of the keys to success is..." and "one of the keys to the success of ... is ...".

Comment: @Mitch It's not "the keys of the success," in the same way it's not "the keys of his car."

Comment: @kiamlaluno: my comment was to point out that, by itself "...one of the keys to the success." ending on 'success' is not right; one expects something to follow...'the success of what?'.

Comment: @Mitch I reported a phrase, not a sentence. You could say the same about "the keys to his car": If the person has two cars, you could ask "To which car are you referring?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comparing usage of *keys to the* versus *keys of the* between 1800 and 2008 provides the following [Google NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=keys+to+the%2Ckeys+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

> http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=keys%20to%20the%2Ckeys%20of%20the&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000

Examples of *keys of the* include:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

The use of the preposition *of* matches with what you expected. However, these uses are very old and seem old-fashioned now.

*Keys to the car* is now idiomatic: even though both *of* and *to* are logical, *to* is used [most often](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=keys+of+the+car%2Ckeys+to+the+car&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

> http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=keys%20of%20the%20car%2Ckeys%20to%20the%20car&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1920&year_end=2000

There is no solid explanation of *why* this shift happened, but over time *keys to* became the idiomatic phrase over *keys of*.

Comment: Excellent! *filler characters*

Comment: I couldn't have said it better myself

Comment: I can't really put it into words, but there is slight difference in meaning of *keys of* and *keys to*. Compare *Keys of my house* and *Keys to my front door*: put this way they sound OK, but if you change prepositions (*keys to my house* and, especially, *keys of my front door*) these phrases start to sound awkward.

Comment: @Philoto: "Keys of my house" sounds awkward to me as does "keys of my front door". In both cases, for me, it's "keys to".

Comment: The shift is even more marked, and the crossover point much earlier, with [the key of/to](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=the+key+of%2Cthe+key+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: Could it be a form of ellipsis?

Comment: I'd be interested to know how much of the "key(s) of" results are actually in the context of music.

Answer (score 3):

"key of" is common when the key is a property of something rather than the key for a lock (whether the lock is literal or metaphorical). So you write a piece of music in the key of C. A really mushy romantic might say something like:

> She read the poem in the key of my soul.

In software development we often talk about key/value pairs, which are used in associative arrays and similar data structures, and "key of" would be more appropriate in that context. We also speak about the "keys of" a keyboard.

Speculating a bit, I'll point out that "of" connotes possession, so "key of" makes sense when the key in question is clearly possessed by, say, a piano or an aria. The relationship indicated by "to" is correspondence:

> He studied the blueprints to the building.
>
> A classic martini is five parts gin to one part vermouth.

It's easy to see that there's always a correspondence between keys and locks, but we don't think of the key or the lock possessing the other. That's why we talk about the "key to" a particular lock and not the "key of" that lock.